# what html element is easiest to render

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a little game with jQuery and and HTML. basically my problem is that when i have too many elements (500+ divs) on the page, it reduces framerate of the game a little. My question is is there any difference in what elements are easiest to render, it needs to be styleable with CSS. I currently use div's, and i've tried paragraph tags but there is no visible difference.

Comment: That almost definitely makes no difference.  Instead, make your CSS simpler, or replace it all with `<canvas>`.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, it is possible your selectors are not optimized.

Answer (score 2):

> I currently use div's, and i've tried paragraph tags but there is no
>   visible difference.

HTML elements are **semantic**. That means that you shouldn't choose one or another because of the styles major browsers give them by default.

In fact, almost all elements behave the same and take the same time to be rendered, assuming they have the same CSS styles.

Only some elements have different behaviors: `<video>`, `<canvas>`, `<a>`, ...

Then, if you want to gain performance:

- Optimize your CSS, independently of the elements it is applied to.

  - Optimize selectors, e.g. avoid `*`
  - Some CSS3 properties like `border-radius` are expensive
- Optimize your JS code, specially reduce DOM interactions
- Consider using a canvas instead of lots of elements.

Comment: Is there a chance that inline SVG elements would be more lightweight than traditional HTML elements?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure, I have never used SVG

Comment: @SimonAndersson It looks cool :) . But if possible, I strongly suggest to use HTML5 `<canvas>`, it will behave much better and I think you won't lose any functionality

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here isn't which element is easiest to render but how each element is styled and displayed. You can make a strong tag appear and act as a div tag and vice-versa so changing element names won't help here.

500 elements is going to be quite intensive for some browser / computer combinations, have you looked into other solutions using the canvas element instead? You are limited to HTML5 only then so, not really for older browsers but it may be worth considering but you can probably get more out of the more modern browsers this way.

Hope this helps out :)

Answer (score 0):

Each element has its own purpose. How can you use a `<p>` tag in place of a `<div>` tag?

All elements take approximately the same time to render, with a few exceptions such as the `<video>` tag.

What increases/decreases the speed is the amount of CSS and JS associated to the element.

**SOLUTION**

> it reduces framerate of the game a little

Try clearing the cache of your browser. If possible, [compress](http://smallerapp.com/) your code, so the browser takes lesser time to understand it.

Comment: Minor typo: I assume `<b>` should be `<p>` since the OP was talking about replacing their divs with paragraph tags.

Comment: uh.. no. Output buffer, minified HTML etc. may improve response time, but it has no effect on the framerate once the document is done loading. No idea how clearing the cache should help either.

Comment: Yeah, but it was a tip to speed up the HTML page.

Comment: but, that's not what the question is about. The question asks about the framerate while animating.

Comment: Clearing the cache does help speed up the browser. Btw, I've edited my answer in accordance with the points you made.

Comment: Still, you're improving the performance of the initial load, with no effect on the framerate.

Comment: Also, minification is not there to reduce the parse time, but rather to improve data transfer time.

Comment: @EisaAdil how does clearing the cache help? For one, you need to reload the stuff you've just washed down the drain.